# After Inserting some rows in UITableView, it is not scrolling in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

Hi I have created UITableView. On Touch of it cell, i am inserting more rows in it. After inserting more rows in UITableView, scroll is not working. This is only happening in ios 7.

Have any one came across this problem??

here is the code of insertion.

```
NSArray *rowIndex = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:[self.lastSelectedIndex section]]];
[self.table beginUpdates];
[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowIndex withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.table endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what does going on your code but if you want to scroll after every add row just call the method bellow (note :- modify the code as per your variable name)

```
-(void)goToBottom
{
     NSInteger lastSectionIndex = MAX(0, [myTableName numberOfSections] - 1);
     NSInteger lastRowIndex = MAX(0, [ myTableName numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1);

     NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

   if([myArray count] > 0)
    {
        [myTableName scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Mits, thanks for reply.  Actually i am not looking for this. The problem is after inserting few more rows in tableview it is not at all scrolling. even my content size (height) is more than the table view height. Any way after inserting rows i am pushing that particular tow to top. `[self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.lastSelectedIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:EXPAND_ANIMATE];`

Comment: i am not clarify actually what you want ?

Comment: i am having a tableview with aroung 10 items. its content height is more than table view height. since table view is child of scroll view. it should start scrolling automatically. till here is working fine. now suppose user is going to touch 2 cell. here am adding 10 more cells in table view. tableview content height is going to increase again. here after insertin 10 more rows, table view is not scrolling. this is only happening in ios7 working fine with other os version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the View with the storyboard? maybe you have to check your constraints.
if your table view occupies all of the space in the view, select it then go to "Editor>pin>top space to superview and bottom space to superview"

Comment: hi, i am creating it programatically. i am not using xib or storyboard. This is working fine in ios 6 5 4. only this is only happening in ios 7.